# I can't go to my desktop tab.(Unable to find requested file.Please check the spelling and try again.)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, lenovo, desktop-environments, desktop-icons

It says **Unable to find requested file.Please check the spelling and try again**.
[image]

And the trash icon missing from desktop.

output of `ls -l ~/`

```
$ls -l ~/
total 91172
drwxrwxr-x  3 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul  7 07:33 Android
-rw-rw-r--  1 shashindu shashindu     1892 Dec  4  2019 deb-pacman_1.0-0.deb.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  6 11:33 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 11 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  6 08:24 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 16 shashindu shashindu    16384 Aug  6 12:22 Downloads
drwxrwxr-x  4 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  5 06:37 eclipse-workspace
drwxrwxr-x  3 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul 25 07:25 Games
-rw-rw-r--  1 shashindu shashindu 80213604 Jul 31 02:37 google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
-rwxrw-r--  1 shashindu shashindu 10808517 Jun 11 02:48 kite-installer
drwxr-xr-x  4 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul 30 21:45 Music
drwxr-xr-x  6 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  6 09:20 Pictures
drwxrwxr-x  4 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul 23 23:21 prefix32
drwxr-xr-x  2 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul  6 13:14 Public
drwxr-xr-x 17 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  6 12:21 snap
drwxrwxr-x  3 shashindu shashindu     4096 Jul 23 05:45 Steam
-rw-rw-r--  1 shashindu shashindu  2259698 May 20  2020 utserver.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  9 shashindu shashindu     4096 Aug  3 19:41 Videos
-rw-rw-r--  1 shashindu shashindu     3220 Dec 19  2018 winehq.key
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/` ? (Edit your question and add the output of this command).

Comment: @PJSingh Now it working.I don't know what happened.but I'll add  `ls -l ~/` output in question.

Comment: I wanted to see if you had the `Desktop` directory and if it was owned by you. I can see that the directory is there and that you do have read, write, and directory access permissions on it.